# In iOS is daylight saving in NSTimeZone broken?

Tags: ios, dst, nstimezone

I have two variables:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZoneMinus5 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: -18000];
NSTimeZone *timeZoneEST = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
```

Tested on a device and on the simulator as well both return `GMT-05:00`.

As I'm writing this the time is `2:55 am (GMT)`. I am in the EST timezone so my time is `10:55pm (GMT-05:00)`, observing Daylight Saving Time on April 15 2011.

However, `[timeZoneEST isDaylightSavingTime]` returns `NO` and `[timeZoneEST daylightSavingTimeOffset]` returns `0`.

If I use `timeZoneEST` to get the current time as a string:

```
NSDate *gmtTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a (z)"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: timeZoneEST];
NSString *timeStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: gmtTime];
```

both the simulator and the device gives me `9:55 PM (GMT-05:00)`.

In my understanding I should be getting `10:55 PM (GMT-05:00)`. Am I wrong or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very confused. To start with, daylight savings time in the US Eastern time zone is -4, not -5. 9:55 PM certainly is 5 hours before 2:55 am; 10:55 PM would be 4 hours before.

Chances are that "EST" is giving you exactly that: Eastern Standard Time without regard for daylight savings time. "EST5EDT" might give you the time zone you are expecting, although (assuming the device uses zoneinfo as the simulator does) "America/New_York" would be preferred.

Comment: indeed, and now I also now what confused me. The value -18000 was sent to the app by my server-side program that runs in a VM that had its time wrong. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `NSTimeZone` to be EST, so it makes sense that `[timeZoneEST isDaylightSavingTime]` returns `NO`. Instead use `[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] daylightSavingTimeOffset];` to get daylight saving time offset for the local time. It should return `3600` seconds.